# Apache VirtualHost answering when I browse to IP address

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I've got a standard build of RHEL6 and I used to be able to browse to the server's `DocumentRoot` using the IP address.

I've since added these two vhosts (just the top section is shown). For some reason, now when I access the server's IP address, the Vhost answers and the wrong `DocumentRoot` is used.

I don't really want to explicitly define a Vhost for `/var/www/html`.

Another note... I have added `NameVirtualHost *:80` to `httpd.conf`.

Any ideas why the vhosts are answering this?

```
==> axxx-http.conf <==

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin beren@xxyy.com
ServerName xxyy.com
ServerAlias www.xxyy.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
<Directory /var/www/site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all

==> axxx-ssl.conf <==

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName xxyy.com
    ServerAlias www.xxyy.com
    ServerAlias admin.xxyy.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/site
<Directory /var/www/site>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you start to use virtual hosts on a webserver you have to make a virtual host for the *normal* server too. If you don't create one, the first virtual host defined will be the default one for any connections to the server not matched by another virtual host ServerName or ServerAlias directive.

Check the section "*Main host goes away*" on this URL for this explanation:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

Comment: Appreciate the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The *:80 tells that vhost to answer on port 80 for every IP.  If you are going to do Name Based Virtual Hosts, you must define a default as *default*:80 with what you want for the default.  You cannot use both vhost and non-vhost configs on the same port.

Comment: I believe its actually `_default_:80` if you chose to use this method instead of the one I suggested above (first virtual host directive being automatically the default one).

Comment: @MattiasAhnberg Actually, if it's specified like that it'll not match the `NameVirtualHost` directive (assuming it's not set to `NameVirtualHost _default_:80`) - that configuration would be inert.  The first to load that matches will always be the default.

Comment: @ShaneMadden If you check my answer above my suggestion is to define the first virtual host as the default one. But you're supposed to define NameVirtualHost as *:80 then create a `_default_:80` for the default virtual host. Check apache documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html#default

Comment: @MattiasAhnberg Indeed - What I am saying that your answer is the only valid one, and that `_default_` doesn't work.  It's only for, quoting from the page you linked, "`an address/port combination that is not used for any other virtual host.`", which isn't true of an address/port combination that has several vhosts on the ip/port combo (as you would in a name-based vhosts setup).